# how java.util.ServiceLoader works?

Tags: java

```
ServiceLoader<A> xyz = ServiceLoader.load(A.class);

xyz.iterator().hasNext() ------> returning false ;
```

I have a text file in "META-INF/services/" named  A containing the name of the class which extends A.

Now why it is returning false .

can anyone please explain me how exactly this works and what may i'm missing .

Comment: Not unless you show us exactly what's inside the A file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include package names both for the filename and contents.

```
META-INF/services/package.A
```

which includes

```
package.Aimpl
package.A2impl
package.A3impl
```

Comment: that part is working now , thnx .
can u tell me how i can put one project on the classpath of other project because now i'm getting ClassNotFoundException for the class inside the files .

Comment: what do you mean by projects? eclipse projects or .jar files or something else?

Comment: eclipse projects , i want to link 2 projects .
the class name inside the file is in another project . so i need to place it in classpath of that project.

i tried putting the jars but it's not working . :(

Comment: i think you can just add a dependence from one project to the other and the other project will be visible to the referencing project. but if that doesnt work you will need to tell a bit about your exec environment. are you launching standalllone java app or deploying into apppserver etc

Comment: i'm deploying the project using ear-projects jar file on JBoss 5.0

Comment: i think the problem is with multiple classloaders. look at stackoverflow.com/questions/7039467/java-serviceloader-with-multiple-classloaders

Comment: i created jars and placed them into EarContent/lib folder and they came into EarLilbraries and now it's working .
thanks a lot